# how to encode a binary PDF from HttpResponse?

Tags: c#, pdf, encoding, httpresponse

I'm getting a binary PDF from HttpResponse, but having trouble getting it in the right format

```
  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
      using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      {
          var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
          {
              byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
              File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\label.pdf", byteArray);
          }


      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `StreamReader`. A `StreamReader` is for turning a stream of bytes into a stream of characters. However, PDFs are binary files, and you shouldn't turn them into text.

Simply copy the bytes that you are downloading directly into a file, without turning them into characters:

```
using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "label.pdf")))
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PDF is bytes, not text - it looks like you're fetching the PDF from an http request, in which case you don't want to use `StreamReader`, `string` or `Encoding` here - you just want the raw bytes. You can probably just use `httpResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(someOtherStream)` where `someOtherStream` is a `FileStream` to the location, i.e.

```cs
using (var target = File.Create(path))
using (var source = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    source.CopyTo(target);
}
```

Comment: the dev who created the cloud function tells me it returns the PDF as binary data. Is that the same as "raw bytes"?

Comment: yes - the key point here being: "not some kind of text encoding"